# page is not going to home screen after signing in using flutter

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I am still a beginner in flutter so I don't have much knowledge about it , so the problem is that I am unable to enter app after signing up application is still showing sign up page even after signing in with  google . so I have created an application where I need to signin and get inside the app it was working before adding support for google to take user info and now it is not going inside the home screen.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:concord/models/user.dart';
import 'package:concord/pages/create_account_page.dart';
import 'package:concord/pages/music_page.dart';
import 'package:concord/pages/profile_page.dart';
import 'package:concord/pages/search_page.dart';
import 'package:concord/pages/timeline_page.dart';
import 'package:concord/pages/upload_page.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

final GoogleSignIn gSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
final usersReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users");

final DateTime timestamp = DateTime.now();
User currentUser;

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool isSignedIn = false;

  PageController pageController;
  int getPageIndex = 0;

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  void initState(){
    //SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
    super.initState();

    pageController = PageController();

    gSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((gSignInAccount) {
      controlSignIn(gSignInAccount);
    }, onError: (gError){
      print("Error Message" + gError);
    });

    gSignIn.signInSilently(suppressErrors: false).then((gSignInAccount){
      controlSignIn(gSignInAccount);
    }).catchError((gError){
      print("Error Message" + gError);
    });

  }

  controlSignIn(GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount) async {
    if (signInAccount != null)
      {
        await saveUserInfoToFireStore();
        setState(() {
          isSignedIn = true;
        });
      } else {
      isSignedIn = false;
    }
  }

  saveUserInfoToFireStore() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount gCurrentUser = gSignIn.currentUser;
    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = await usersReference.doc(gCurrentUser.id).get();

    if(!documentSnapshot.exists){
      final username = await Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateAccountPage()));

      usersReference.doc(gCurrentUser.id).set({
        "id": gCurrentUser.id,
        "profileName": gCurrentUser.displayName,
        "username": username,
        "url": gCurrentUser.photoUrl,
        "email": gCurrentUser.email,
        "bio": "",
        "timestamp": timestamp,
      });
      documentSnapshot = await usersReference.doc(gCurrentUser.id).get();

    }

    currentUser = User.fromDocument(documentSnapshot);

  }

  void dispose(){
    pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  loginUser(){
    gSignIn.signIn();
  }
  logoutUser(){
    gSignIn.signOut();
  }


  whenPageChanges(int pageIndex){
    setState(() {
      this.getPageIndex = pageIndex;
    });
  }

  onTapChangePage(int pageIndex){
    pageController.animateToPage( pageIndex, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400), curve: Curves.bounceInOut);
  }

  Scaffold buildHomeScreen() {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView(
          children : <Widget>[

            TimeLinePage(),
            SearchPage(),
            MusicPage(),
            UploadPage(),
            ProfilePage(),
          ],
        controller: pageController,
        onPageChanged: whenPageChanges,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(55.0),
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(50.0),
          ),
          child: CupertinoTabBar(
            currentIndex: getPageIndex,
            onTap: onTapChangePage,
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            activeColor: Colors.blue,
            inactiveColor: Colors.blueGrey,
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home)),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.search)),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.music_note,)),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline_outlined)),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.person)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      );

    //return ElevatedButton.icon(onPressed: logoutUser, icon: Icon(Icons.close), label:  Text("Sign Out"));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mq = MediaQuery.of(context);

    final greetings = Container(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 110.0, 0.0, 0.0),
            child: Text(
              'Its nice to meet you.',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 250.0, 0.0, 0.0),
            child: Text(
              'Lets get in.',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

    final logo = Image.asset(
      "assets/icons/concord_white.png",
      height: mq.size.height / 4,
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
    );

    final googleButton = Container(
      height: 40.0,
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: loginUser,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.white, style: BorderStyle.solid, width: 1.0),
              color: Colors.transparent,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                child: ImageIcon(AssetImage('assets/icons/google_white.png')),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 10.0),
              Center(
                child: Text(
                  "Sign in with Google",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );



    Scaffold buildSignInScreen() {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          key: _formKey,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.bottomRight,
              end: Alignment.topLeft,
              colors: [
                Color.fromRGBO(49, 57, 125, 1.0),
                Color.fromRGBO(137, 205, 174, 1.0),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                greetings,
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                logo,
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                googleButton,
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    if (isSignedIn) {
      return buildHomeScreen();
    } else {
      return buildSignInScreen();
    }
  }
}
```